# Python 3.x deleting lowest numerical value in a two-dimensional list

Tags: python, list

I'm sorting a two-dimensional list which goes like this [[a, 1, 2], [b, 3, 4], [c, 5, 6]]. I tried sorting the list till I realised that in doing so I only sorted one value and the largest value may get deleted e.g. [[a, 4, 2][b, 3, 5][c, 7, 8]]. So I decided to use a for loop and create a second list where the lowest value of each list will be put in there and then deleted from the main list but that didn't work so I can't think of any good ideas that are efficient.

Main code problem:

```
if Class == 1:
    print('\n\t{}'.format(Class_1))
    Class_1.sort()
    print('\n\t{}'.format(Class_1))
    Class_1_length = len(Class_1)
    Class_1.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
    print(Class_1)
    for Student in range(0, Class_1_length):
        if Class_1[Student][1] > Class_1[Student][2]:
            #Method of removing value 2
        if Class_1[Student][1] < Class_1[Student][2]:
            #Method of removing value 1
        if Class_1[Student][1] == Class_1[Student][2]:
            #Method of removing value 2
    print(Class_1)
```

When I tried using pop it would tell me that the string could not be interpreted as an integer but by adding int() in side the pop() it would tell me the .pop index was out of range. When I created a second list the [x for x in list1 if x is not in list2] or something like that didn't do anything.

I would like a method that would work no matter what the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are in this list - [[a, 1, 2], [b, 3, 4], [c, 5, 6]]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Say the list was [[a, 3, 7], [b, 8, 8], [c, 6, 5]]. I want the list to output like this: [[a, 7], [b, 8], [c, 6]].

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension to construct a new list but you need to reconstruct each of the elements, e.g.:

```
>>> d = [['a', 1, 2], ['b', 3, 4], ['c', 5, 6]]
>>> [(x, max(y, z)) for x,y,z in d]
[('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 6)]
>>> d = [['a', 3, 7], ['b', 8, 8], ['c', 6, 5]]
>>> [(x, max(y, z)) for x,y,z in d]
[('a', 7), ('b', 8), ('c', 6)]
```

Comment: When I add it to the code would I leave it as x, y and z or do I change it.

Comment: @jaxt65 You don't have to change it, but you can

Comment: They are locally defined, you can use them as is are any other name that you feel is appropriate, e.g. `[(name, max(test_1, test_2)) for name,test_1,test_2 in Class_1]` would equally work.

Comment: Would this be place on its own or in the for loop.

Comment: This is a loop just assign it to an output variable, e.g. `results = [...]`. If you want to update the existing variable then you can `Class_1 = [...]`.

Comment: Just update your question, you can't format code in a comment. Or if it is a separate question, start a new one.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find anything.